# export ascii xml from ms access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, export

I have an MS ACCESS DB .accdb, and would like to convert it to mysql.
The problem is that the MS Access data is in armscii and I want to save it in mysql with utf8

I already created a converting script with php

The problem is that i don't have any ODBC and can't use ODBC, so I tried to export MS Access data to xml but it has no ARMSCII encoding, only utf8 or utf 16

Can you please give me an advice how to get my goal !
Thank you

Comment: Can you not even install the ODBC driver? A quick google looks like with just the driver you could output your database to a SQL file which you should be able to then import into MySQL (you might need a few changes)

Comment: The thing is that i don't have permission to install driver n the server ... i need to do that on the server

Comment: No you just need it where Access is running. (If Access is running on a server can you not just move the file to another client). You could even install MySQL locally, with all the ODBC setup. Import into the local mysql and then move the MySQL database over in a native format.